# RabbitMQ management API call failed: HTTP 500: Internal Server Error

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I am using Celery Flower with RabbitMQ as message broker. However I am :getting nasty error

> ERROR - RabbitMQ management API call failed: HTTP 500: Internal Server Error

every time I try to access RabbitMQ queues on RabbitMQ management interface (http://localhost:15672/#/queues) or Celery Broker (http://localhost:5555/broker).

Here is a detailed log info:

> =ERROR REPORT==== 15-Jan-2017::23:12:19 === webmachine error: path="/api/queues/%2F" {error,{error,function_clause,
>   [{mochijson2,json_encode_string_unicode,
>   [{error,[],<<166,65,92,180,0,0,0,0,0>>}, {encoder,null,false}, """],
>   [{file,"src/mochijson2.erl"},{line,274}]},
>   {mochijson2,'-json_encode_proplist/2-fun-0-',3,
>   [{file,"src/mochijson2.erl"},{line,198}]},
>   {lists,foldl,3,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1248}]},
>   {mochijson2,json_encode_proplist,2,
>   [{file,"src/mochijson2.erl"},{line,202}]},
>   {mochijson2,'-json_encode_proplist/2-fun-0-',3,
>   [{file,"src/mochijson2.erl"},{line,199}]},
>   {lists,foldl,3,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1248}]},
>   {mochijson2,json_encode_proplist,2,
>   [{file,"src/mochijson2.erl"},{line,202}]},
>   {mochijson2,'-json_encode_array/2-fun-0-',3,
>   [{file,"src/mochijson2.erl"},{line,189}]}]}}

RabbitMQ web management gives me:

> Got response code 500 with body {"error":"Internal Server
>   Error","reason":"{error,{error,function_clause,\n
>   [{mochijson2,json_encode_string_unicode,\n
>   [{error,[],<<166,65,92,180,0,0,0,0,0>>},\n {encoder,null,false},\n
>   "\""],\n [{file,"src/mochijson2.erl"},{line,274}]},\n
>   {mochijson2,'-json_encode_proplist/2-fun-0-',3,\n
>   [{file,"src/mochijson2.erl"},{line,198}]},\n
>   {lists,foldl,3,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1248}]},\n
>   {mochijson2,json_encode_proplist,2,\n
>   [{file,"src/mochijson2.erl"},{line,202}]},\n
>   {mochijson2,'-json_encode_proplist/2-fun-0-',3,\n
>   [{file,"src/mochijson2.erl"},{line,199}]},\n
>   {lists,foldl,3,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1248}]},\n
>   {mochijson2,json_encode_proplist,2,\n
>   [{file,"src/mochijson2.erl"},{line,202}]},\n
>   {mochijson2,'-json_encode_array/2-fun-0-',3,\n
>   [{file,"src/mochijson2.erl"},{line,189}]}]}}\n"}

I am using:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- Python 2.7.6
- Flower 0.9.1
- Celery 4.0.2
- RabbitMQ 3.6.6
- Erlang/OTP 19

RabbitMQ management plugin is enabled (rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management).

Here is the output for rabbitmqctl status:

> [{pid,28609},  {running_applications,
>        [{rabbitmq_management,"RabbitMQ Management Console","3.6.6"},
>         {amqp_client,"RabbitMQ AMQP Client","3.6.6"},
>         {rabbitmq_management_agent,"RabbitMQ Management Agent","3.6.6"},
>         {rabbitmq_web_dispatch,"RabbitMQ Web Dispatcher","3.6.6"},
>         {rabbit,"RabbitMQ","3.6.6"},
>         {os_mon,"CPO  CXC 138 46","2.4.1"},
>         {webmachine,"webmachine","1.10.3"},
>         {mochiweb,"MochiMedia Web Server","2.13.1"},
>         {ssl,"Erlang/OTP SSL application","8.1"},
>         {public_key,"Public key infrastructure","1.3"},
>         {crypto,"CRYPTO","3.7.2"},
>         {rabbit_common,[],"3.6.6"},
>         {xmerl,"XML parser","1.3.12"},
>         {asn1,"The Erlang ASN1 compiler version 4.0.4","4.0.4"},
>         {syntax_tools,"Syntax tools","2.1.1"},
>         {mnesia,"MNESIA  CXC 138 12","4.14.2"},
>         {compiler,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","7.0.3"},
>         {ranch,"Socket acceptor pool for TCP protocols.","1.2.1"},
>         {inets,"INETS  CXC 138 49","6.3.4"},
>         {sasl,"SASL  CXC 138 11","3.0.2"},
>         {stdlib,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","3.2"},
>         {kernel,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","5.1.1"}]},  {os,{unix,linux}},  {erlang_version,
>        "Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:64] [kernel-poll:true]\n"},  {memory,
>        [{total,112070616},
>         {connection_readers,471152},
>         {connection_writers,171664},
>         {connection_channels,494680},
>         {connection_other,407232},
>         {queue_procs,534792},
>         {queue_slave_procs,0},
>         {plugins,2121728},
>         {other_proc,12017232},
>         {mnesia,93584},
>         {mgmt_db,5114688},
>         {msg_index,49304},
>         {other_ets,1902144},
>         {binary,52694768},
>         {code,24783822},
>         {atom,1033401},
>         {other_system,10180425}]},  {alarms,[]},  {listeners,[{clustering,25672,"::"},{amqp,5672,"::"}]}, 
>   {vm_memory_high_watermark,0.4},  {vm_memory_limit,6691391078}, 
>   {disk_free_limit,50000000},  {disk_free,59039645696}, 
>   {file_descriptors,
>        [{total_limit,3996},
>         {total_used,23},
>         {sockets_limit,3594},
>         {sockets_used,20}]},  {processes,[{limit,1048576},{used,454}]},  {run_queue,0},  {uptime,2498},  {kernel,{net_ticktime,60}}]

Here is how I run Celery:

Start 3 celery workers:

```
celery worker -A celeryapp --config celeryconfig --workdir /proj -l DEBUG --soft-time-limit=3500 --time-limit=3600 --autoscale=2,1 -S /proj/states.db -s /proj/celerybeat-schedule.db -f /proj/logs/celery_worker_1_%n%I.log --pidfile /tmp/celery_w1.pid -n worker1@%d
celery worker -A celeryapp --config celeryconfig --workdir /proj -l DEBUG --soft-time-limit=3500 --time-limit=3600 --autoscale=2,1 -S /proj/states.db -s /proj/celerybeat-schedule.db -f /proj/logs/celery_worker_2_%n%I.log --pidfile /tmp/celery_w2.pid -n worker2@%d
celery worker -A celeryapp --config celeryconfig --workdir /proj -l DEBUG --soft-time-limit=3500 --time-limit=3600 --autoscale=2,1 -S /proj/states.db -s /proj/celerybeat-schedule.db -f /proj/logs/celery_worker_3_%n%I.log --pidfile /tmp/celery_w3.pid -n worker3@%d
```

Start celery beat:

```
celery beat -A celeryapp --config celeryconfig --workdir /proj -l DEBUG -s /proj/celerybeat-schedule.db -f /proj/logs/celery_%n%I.log --pidfile /tmp/celery.pid
```

Start celery flower:

```
celery flower -A celeryapp --workdir=/proj/ --broker=amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672// --broker-api=http://guest:guest@localhost:15672/api/ --db=/proj/flower.db --logging=debug --basic-auth=guest:guest
```

I posted this question in Github issues of RabbitMQ but it was [rejected](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/issues/1081)

Comment: Wich Erlang version are you using ? type this command `erl -eval 'erlang:display(erlang:system_info(otp_release)), halt().'  -noshell`

Comment: Erlang version is "R16B03".

Comment: It is updated to Erlang/OTP 19 now but problem still exists

Answer (score 0):

Your Elang Version it is a bit old.

Update it using the last version, the management UI requires a new Erlang Version

https://www.erlang-solutions.com/resources/download.html

```
wget https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang-solutions_1.0_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i erlang-solutions_1.0_all.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install erlang
```

Comment: Following steps above I installed new version "Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.2] [source] [64-bit]" but problem remains.

Comment: can you please update the question with the new `rabbitmqctl status` ?